# save webcam captured image into local folder without using FileSavePicker

Tags: windows-store-apps, window, winrt-async

I am using  Below Code to save image but it save image after `filesavepicker` save image but I want to save image direct into local folder without using
`filesavepicker`,Please suggest me any Solution for this, thanks in Advance.

```
webcam private async Task SavePhoto(IRandomAccessStream mediaStream)
 {

   FileSavePicker photoSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
   photoSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;                              
   var mediaFile = await photoSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
   await SaveStreamToFileAsync(mediaStream, mediaFile);

}
```

I want to save this stream data in image format direct to local folder without using  `filesavepicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `StorageFile` inside the app's LocalData. Then pass this `StorageFile` to your function.

```
StorageFolder dirLocal = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile  mediaFile = await dirLocal.CreateFileAsync("mediaFile.abc");
SaveStreamToFileAsync(mediaStream, mediaFile);
```